# QListView that always has one item selected

Tags: qt, qlistview

Is it possible to have a QListView that *always* has a single item selected (unless there are no items)? By default it seems that you can have no selection (although weirdly the `selectionModel()` always thinks there is a selection even if the GUI doesn't draw it).

Comment: How do you know that selectionModel indicates selection when there is actually no selection?

Comment: Because `myList->selectionModel()->currentChanged(const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex& previous)` is always emitted when I start my app, and `current->isValid()` is true and the row/column are 0. There does seem to be some distinction between 'the current item' and 'the current selection' but the docs are unclear and I *am* using the selection model so...

Comment: Yes, there is a distinction between `current item` and `selected item`. Current item is not necessarily a selected one. The current item is drown with a dotted outline (not always visible), but the background color remains the same if there is no selection. To check whether anything is selected you should use rather `QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes()` function, which, I expect, returns 0 for the newly created view. And in order to select something by default you should use `QItemSelectionModel::select()` function.

Comment: Aha using `QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged()` did the trick thanks. Yeah I think it was a bit confusing about the 'current item' because it isn't drawn at all on OSX.